# How do I refresh a series of panels using a Partial Refresh

Tags: javascript, custom-controls, xpages

I have a form with 6 different Custom Controls. Within each of these CCs are panels that render or not based on a set of values from the first CCs. How can I refresh all of them at the same time with a Partial Refresh (I do not want to do a Full Refresh) once the set of values is answered?

Answer (score 5):

Put all your CC inside a div or panel and refresh that or use this from tim tripcony

http://www.timtripcony.com/blog.nsf/d6plinks/TTRY-84B6VP

Answer (score 1):

If you put all your custom controls in different dynamic Content control using extLib you can refresh them all using client or server side events.

```
XSP.showContent("dyn1","cc1");
XSP.showContent("dyn2","cc2");
```